# Proof by contradiction that if $f$ and $f\circ g$ are injective, then $g$ is injective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I would like to see if this proof by contradiction is correct.

Prove by contradiction that if $f$ and $f\circ g$ are injective, then $g$ is injective.

The premise for contradiction is:

> $f$ and $f\circ g$ are injective, and $g$ is not injective.

Proof: Let $g : A\to B$ and $f:B\to C$.
Suppose $g$ is not injective and $f\circ g$ is injective.

Because $g$ is not injective, there exists $m$ and $n$ in $A$ such that $m\neq n$ and $g(m)=g(n)$. 
 Clearly, $f(g(m)) = f(g(n))$. Hence $$(f\circ g)(m) = (f\circ g)(n)\tag{1}$$

Because $f\circ g$ is injective. Thus, universal instantiation on the definition, give us:
$$(f\circ g)(m) = (f\circ g)(n) \implies m=n.\tag{2}$$
Modus Ponens on $(1)$ and $(2)$, we conclude that $m=n$. This contradicts the fact that $m\neq n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, "Because $f\circ g$ is injective" is a sentence fragment.

Also, there is no need to argue by contradiction. Your proof is fine, sure, but it can be rewritten as follows.

Suppose $f\circ g$ is injective. Consider $m,n$ such that $g(m)=g(n)$. We have

$$\begin{align}
(f\circ g)(m)&=f(g(m))\\
&=f(g(n))\\
&=(f\circ g)(n),
\end{align}$$

so that $m=n$. Thus $g$ is injective.

---

Note that we do not need $f$ to be injective.

Comment: Thank you! for the editing as well. May I also ask about proving an implication?   Tho, it is of the form $p \implies q$. But in our case, the definition of p and q are also implications. Hence, $ (a \implies b) \implies (c \implies d)$. While proving, what can we assume and what not? Can we assume multiple things in cases like this? Do we only allow to assume $p$, $a$, and $c$ to be true just like you did, and then somehow deduct that $d$ is true? Or is there another way we can assume? Hopefully, my question is not too confusing.

Comment: You're welcome, @ChhangsrengP. That question is too far afield to address here. Please consider asking it as a separate question (provided you cannot find a duplicate).

Comment: I will try tomorrow, I am too late at night right now. Btw, for some reason, I can't mention you.

Answer (score 4):

Your argument is correct, but in the course of the proof you showed
$$g(m) = g(n) \implies f(g(m)) = f(g(n)) \implies m = n$$
so that $g$ is injective. There is no need for a proof by contradiction.

You didn't need to assume $f$ injective.