# What can be assume when proving an implication in which the hypothesis or conclusion is also an implication?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

The topic is about proving something of the form: 
$ p \implies q $ in which $p$ is "$a \implies b$" and q is "$c \implies d$". Thus, it can be rewritten as: 
$(a \implies b) \implies (c \implies d)$

Also, this question focus on **direct proof**.

**What I already know:** Now, I already know that to prove an implication, we can start by assuming the hypothesis is true and somehow deduct that q is true. Hence, for $p \implies q$, we can assume that $p$ is true, then try to show that $q$ is logically followed. However, I now have a problem when $p$ and $q$ by themselves are also an implication. I don't think I can show that q follows just by assuming only p is true in this case. What can and can't be assumed?

**My understanding**(let me know if this thought process is wrong): I think we can't prove this by assuming $b, d$ or $q$ to be true because both of them are the conclusion. However, we can assume that $a$ and $c$ are true since they are both a hypothesis, and **at the same time** also assume p is true since p itself is also a hypothesis. Now, Can our proof be complete by assuming that $a, c $, and $p$ are true and show that $d$ is logically follows from that 3 assumptions?

Also, if we can assume $p$ and $a$ to be true, can we use Modus Ponen on them to deduct that b is also true?

Below is just an **example** of such problem: 
[Proof by contradiction that if $f$ and $f\circ g$ are injective, then $g$ is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4624492/proof-by-contradiction-that-if-f-and-f-circ-g-are-injective-then-g-is-inj/4624501?noredirect=1#comment9753623_4624501)
The definition of injective function is 
 $\forall{x}\forall{y}(f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b) $. It would seem that the question ask us to prove.
"if $f \circ g$ is injective, then $g$ is injective". hence,
$$((f \circ g)(m) = (f \circ g)(n) \implies m=n) \implies (g(m)=g(n) \implies m=n)$$ which is of the form
$p \implies q$ and $p$ is "$a \implies b$" and $q$ is "$c \implies d"$ for which

> p is "$(f \circ g)(m) = (f \circ g)(n) \implies m=n$"
>
> q is "$g(m)=g(n) \implies m=n$"
>
> a is "$(f \circ g)(m) = (f \circ g)(n)$
>
> b is "$m=n$"
>
> c is "$g(m)=g(n)$"
>
> d is "$m=n$

The accepted answer starts by assuming $f \circ g$ is injective, which is the same as assuming $p$ is true. Then assume g(m) = g(n), which is the same as assuming $c$ is true, then he is able to show that $d$ is follow. It seems that he only needs to assume $p$ and $c$ to show that $d$ is follow. However, can I also assume "$a$" is true? Also, $p$ and $a$ are sufficient to deduct that m=n. Do I still need to show that m=n is followed by $c$ rather than $p$ and $a$?

Note: I also want to sorry if my question is very confusing or if I am confused about some very obvious stuff. I have no tutor/school yet, and learn from reading book only and my knowledge may have gaps on obvious stuff.

Comment: Note that $A\implies B$ is ONLY false , if $A$ is true and $B$ is false. In a proof of such an implication , we only need the case that $A$ is true (otherwise there is nothing to prove). Now apply this on the case that $A$ and $B$ are itself implications and use the same criterion.

Comment: While I'm not sure what the real question is, the following may help: One can show that $(a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow (c \rightarrow d)$ is logically equivalent to $((a \rightarrow b) \wedge c) \rightarrow d$. This can be shown e.g. by comparing truth tables. So to prove $(a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow (c \rightarrow d)$, you can assume both $a \rightarrow b$ and $c$, and use these two assumptions to show $d$. But in general, you cannot assume that $a$ itself is true.

Comment: Have you considered proof by cases? Use $a\implies b ~\equiv~ \neg a \lor b$. Case 1: Prove $\neg a \implies (c\implies d)$. Case 2: Prove $b \implies (c\implies d)$